# How to Pass objects between classes

Tags: c#, object

So what I'm trying to do here is pass the same copy of a class (`class A`) to another class (`class B`), but `class B` is instanced in `class A`.

Using a `new` statement in `class B` won't work because it would cause an infinite loop, as well as creating a new instance of it, when I want to be able to use variables from the 1st instance of `class A`.

I know about `object.equals()` but I can't use it until I define the `class A`'s object in `class B`. Just using `object.equals` results in a null reference.

```
public partial class class_A : Form
{
    public class_B _class_B = new class_B;
    public Int32 var; 

    private void setclassA()
    {
        _class_B._class_A.equals(this);
    }
}

public class class_B
{
    public class_A _class_A;        // I know this is null
    // code
}
```

Like I said I want to avoid instancing a new copy of class A because I want the values in class A to be set.

I've tried using a method to do it but still get a null reference.

Comment: You're _completely_ misunderstanding `Equals()`.

Comment: `class_B._class_A = this` is the right way, `Equals` is a check to verify that the two instances are equal (which they can't be in this case).

Comment: By the way, when you post code as an example, please make sure it compiles. This helps us copy the code and debug your problem, not poor code. There is a lot here that won't compile, and never would compile.

Comment: It's against principles to publish the reference of an object before it's complete eg pass the this reference in the constructor to other objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `A` in the constructor of `B`:

```
public class A
{
   private B _b;

   public A()
   {
       _b = new B(this);
   }
}

public class B
{
    private A _a;

    public B(A a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments you're completely misunderstanding `.Equals()`. It's used to compare whether two objects are equal not clone / pass references.

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

You're 75% there. As Ron mentioned, just change `.equals(this)` to `= this` as follows:

```
_class_B._class_A = this;
```

## Explanation

If we want to pass the same copy of `ClassA` to `ClassB`, and to do that when we instantiate `ClassB` inside of `ClassA`, then we use the `this` keyword, which represents the current instance of a class.

Though there are other ways to give `this` to `ClassB`, the below example shows two:

1. pass `this` to the constructor and do the property assignment in `ClassB` or
2. assign `this` directly to a property in `ClassB`.

The key for you is that `=` is an assignment operator whereas `Equals()` checks whether two variables refer to the same object or not.

## Example

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB MyClassB1 { get; set; }
    public ClassB MyClassB2 { get; set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        // pass `this` to the constructor
        this.MyClassB1 = new ClassB(this);

        // pass `this` directly to a property in `ClassB`
        this.MyClassB2 = new ClassB();
        this.MyClassB2.MyClassA = this;
    }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassA MyClassA { get; set; }

    public ClassB() { }

    public ClassB(ClassA classA)
    {
        // do property assignment in the constructor
        this.MyClassA = classA;
    }
}
```

## Proof of Concept

[This runs as a Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VLqCiT) and prints out "They are the same object," and some other things too in the more recent version.

```
using System;   
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var classA = new ClassA();

        if(classA.Equals(classA.MyClassB1.MyClassA) &&
           classA.Equals(classA.MyClassB2.MyClassA) &&
           classA.MyClassB1.MyClassA.Equals(classA.MyClassB2.MyClassA))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("They are the same object.");
        }
    }
}
```

An important note is that, when we use this, we're giving `ClassB` a *reference to* `ClassA` not a copy of it. These are very different things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class A
{
    public B Instance_B;

    public A(B b)
    {
         Instance_B = b;
    }
}

public class B
{
    public A Instance_A;

    public B()
    {
         Instance_A = new A(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to teach good practices, use public properties, not public fields.

Answer (score -2):

Use `get; set;`

In `Class A`:

```
public partial class class_A : Form
{
    Class_B B = new Class_B();
    B.Class_A = this;
    public Int32 var;
}
```

Then in `Class B`:

```
public class class_B
{
    Class_A A { get; set; }
    // code
}
```

Comment: Its a way, but purely using get;set; (Properties) does not solve or change the actual problem at hand.