# How to share a string between 2 C# classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my first class i have this Code:

```
public string getUser()
    {
        string UserName = metroTextBox4.Text;
        return UserName;
    }
    
    public string EmailAddr()
    {
        string Addr = metroTextBox1.Text;
        return Addr;
    }
```

And in my other class i have this code:

```
private async Task kka(int value)
    {
        var senderg = new SmtpSender(() => new SmtpClient("localhost")

        {
            EnableSsl = false,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            Port = 25
            

        });


        Email.DefaultSender = senderg;

        var email = await Email
            .From("myEmail@example.com")
            .To($"{EmailAddr()}", $"{getUser()}") //At getUser() and at EmailAddr i have the errors
            .Subject("Salut")
            .Body("Mersi ca mi-ai cumparat produsul, sa ai pofta!" +
            $"Comanda ta a avut valoarea de {value} lei")
            .SendAsync();
    }
```

The errors are "The name 'EmailAddr' does not exist in the current context" and "The name 'getUser' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You need a reference to the other class (seems to be a form). `frm.EmailAddr()` and `frm.getUser()`. You can pass a form reference to the sender class in the constructor. See: [How to Pass objects between classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30066433/880990). You can replace the methods by a readonly property like this (much easier): `public string getUser => metroTextBox4.Text;`

Comment: OT for your own sanity, please rename those textboxes to something useful (like Username)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create an object of the first class inside the second class's method and reference the methods EmailAddr() and getUser() using that reference.

```
FirstClass fObj = new FirstClass();
fObj.EmailAddr();
fObj.getUser();
```

or as rightly mentioned in the comment by Olivier, you can pass a reference to the first class in the constructor of the second class

Answer (score 0):

so many different approaches. will give you first 2
**option 1**: send email as parameter to function

```
private async Task kka(int value, string email)
```

**option 2**: use static class to set property. so you can read it from other class

```
void Main()
{
    EmailAddr2.EmailAddress = EmailAddr();
    TODO();
}

private void TODO()
{
    EmailAddr2.EmailAddress.Dump();
}


public string EmailAddr()
{
    string Addr = "my@email.com";
    return Addr;
}


public static class EmailAddr2
{
    public static string EmailAddress {get;set;}
}
```